# How can I fix Err 01 with a film-era Sigma lens on a Canon DSLR?

Tags: lens, canon, troubleshooting, compatibility

I have a new Canon EOS Kiss camera and a friend of mine has a Sigma Aspherical IF 28-200mm lens she used on an old Canon EOS *film* camera (old as in 10 years or so). I tried using the lens on my camera. The auto focus worked fine but when I tried to take a picture the camera froze with the following error:

> #### Err 01
>
> Communications between the camera and lens is faulty.
>   Clean the lens contacts.

I don't think my contacts need cleaning because the camera works fine with a 18-55mm lens.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 8):

Is it a third-party lens or a Canon one? It is a well known fact that some older Sigma lenses in particular have problems with the electronic interface with newer Canon camera bodies.

Comment: I know Sigma will sometimes "re-chip" older lenses to work with newer cameras — do you think that might be a possibility here?

Comment: I have no personal experience with this.. I know a lot of people had it done some years ago (I think compatibility was OK with the classic EOS 1D and broke after that, so it has been a while). Don't know if Sigma still offers this service, for such an old lens. If it's a 150 dollar 70-300 piece of junk I doubt it would be worth the effort in any case :)

Answer (score 8):

> I don't think my contacts need cleaning because the camera works fine
>   with a 18-55mm lens.

You could try cleaning the other side of the contact point, that being the contacts on the *lens*.

Answer (score 5):

This is old question but problem is still actual on old lenses. What you need is protocol interface which converts aperture change command from camera to lens. Please see my article at this link where is problem cause and it's solution described in detail http://butterflybikers.cz/index.php/cz/elektronika/item/1-canon-eos-protocol-convertor-for-old-sigma-lens .

For those who don't want to read whole article I will try to describe problem in short. Old EOS cameras (at moment we can say very old) was using different digital command on SPI bus which tell lens to adjust aperture to some value. For some reason Canon changed that command (old was 0x12 new is 0x13). Result is that your old 3rd party lens is unable to set aperture so gets ERROR 01 because camera cannot set aperture in lens. Solution is easy, add processor to signal path which will convert new command to old one so lens will understand it. See link above for more technical details, HW and SW sources.

Comment: can  you please summarise the content of the link in your answer. Also, are you associated with that site? If so, please disclose.

Comment: Yes I'm author of article on that site, tell me if post should be removed.

Comment: You need to add that information into your post, including the disclosure.

Comment: Added that information and hoved short description into answer to make it more clear. Thank you for guidance.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same lenses and the same problem, but I noticed that if you open the aperture to 5.6 (200mm) you can take photos... you have to fully open the aperture on manual settings. If the size is bigger, you have Error 1.

Answer (score 0):

I use a thin extension tube with no contacts. Is all manual now but usable.

Comment: Did you lose the ability focus to infinity?